Is there a version of \glsresetall that allows me to reset all abbreviations temporarily?
I want to use \glsresetall in a figure caption in my overleaf document, and then have it go back to the previous gls counts afterward. ie, I only want abbreviations to be redefined in the figure caption.
I am using \usepackage[acronym, style=long, nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}.
Thanks for any help!
For example:

    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
    \usepackage[acronym, style=long, nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}
    
    \makeglossaries
    \setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
    \glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{firstuc}

    \newacronym{abbr}{short abbreviation}{long abbreviation}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    This is the first sentence so abbr shows as long abbreviation (short abbreviation): \gls{abbr}. In the second sentence it shows abbr as short abbreviation only: \gls{abbr}.
    
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{picture_name.png}
        \caption{ This caption has abbr as long abbreviation (short abbreviation): \gls{abbr}, as it is treated as a new instance of the abbreviation for the caption only.}
        \label{fig:fig_name}
    \end{figure}
    
    This sentence has abbr as short abbreviation again: \gls{abbr}, as it is not the first use in the main text..
    
    \end{document}

``'


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do nt have to guess what you are doing ...

Hello Mensch, it's as I stated in the post, i have a figure with a caption and want to have long forms of abbreviation with (short form) in the figure, but don't want to resetall for the whole document, and doing it individually for every abbreviation defeats the point of using the acronym package. I have added a brief example.

I can't reproduce the behavior, first there are errors because you use \gls(abbr) instead of \gls{abbr}, there is a typo in the second instance (abbs), and the graphicx package is missing. After this is solved all instances show short abbreviation only.

Sorry, I have fixed the example by adding some of the acronym package definitions i was missing and the errors you pointed out. It should run now to show my issue!

Isn't there a gls command that says "use the long version here"?  Is that what you're trying to have happen?

Indeed as @Teepeemm mentioned using \glsfirst{abbr} in the caption produces the desired output (if I understood the requirement correctly), is that what you are looking for?

Thanks, I'll try that, I was just wondering if there was a better way to deliniate one paragraph as 'separate' for the acronym count use, it would be a little less tedius that using \glsfirst each time as I have to be quite vigilant with texts changes using \glsfirst.
